# Calculate energy of signals

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

> Consider the following two signals
>
> $$\begin{aligned} x(t) &= e^{-kt} u(t)\\\\ y(t) &= x(t) \,\frac{\sin(\theta t)}{\pi t}\end{aligned}$$
>
> Determine the relation between $k$ and $\theta$ so that the energy of $y$ is half of the energy of $x$.

---

What I did was the following.

$$\mathcal{E}_x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\vert x(t)\vert^2 = \frac{1}{2k}$$

$$\mathcal{E}_y = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\vert X(f)P_F(f) \vert^2 = \frac{\theta/\pi}{k^2+\theta^2}$$

with

$$P_F(f) = \begin{cases} 1 && -\frac F2 <f< \frac F2\\ 0 && \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

where $F=\frac{\theta}{\pi}$. A classmate suggested to use the duality property of the $\mathscr{F}$ transform, meaning $$\mathscr{F}\Bigl[\mathscr{F}\left[x(t)\right]\Bigr]=x(-t)$$ but I can't see where or how.

Comment: More detail would be nice. For example, you could mention that you used Parseval's theorem to compute $\mathcal E_y$.

Comment: You already did 99% of the work. I don't understand where you got stuck.

Comment: I don't know where to go from there, because I don't know how to get to a meaningful answer. Also, since the problem is part of a quiz, I have four possible answers. Since I got stuck at the point of my original post, I tried to substitute each of the answers and none of them worked. Should I add them in the post?

Comment: Just use $\mathcal E_x = 2 \mathcal E_y$ and you obtain an equation in $k$ and $\theta$. Done. If the equation does not match any of the four possible answers, then either you made a mistake, or the quiz-maker did.